# OpenCV human head (not just face) "extraction" from photographs

Tags: opencv, face-detection

While I've learnt how to detect faces in OpenCV, I would like to take it a bit further, to detect the outlines of a whole human head (frontal only, for now), i.e. with hair, and up to chin. How can this be done using OpenCV ?

The photographs from which I wish to perform this extraction, could have some simple constraints, like well-lit background, although putting strict constraint like green/blue screen might be possible, but I'd prefer to avoid it, if possible.

Comment: What about looking for concentric and slightly bigger contour than the face, after detecting face.

Comment: Thanks for the comments Pervez. If I understood your suggestion correctly, you mean to say that I should start with the bounding box around the detected face, and incrementally 'grow-out' trying to do contour-detection within it ?

Comment: why dont you use Upperbody cascade file for detection. http://alereimondo.no-ip.org/OpenCV/34 use Head and shoulder cascade file

Comment: Thanks Rahul. It seems interesting, will dig into it see if it can be of help. As such, I specifically want to avoid the neck & shoulder... just the face, nothing more, and nothing less.

Answer (score 2):

You may start finding omega shape in the upper part of body ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ql6FU.jpg)). in Omega shape you can find the upper object (head) easily, by fitting ellipse or circles ([see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17159964/opencvs-fitellipse-sometimes-returns-completely-wrong-ellipses) ). Do not forget that you can handle some background issues to get better results.  [This is a paper](http://kst.buu.ac.th/proceedings/KST2011/docs/en06.pdf) explaining some important steps