# OpenCV's fitEllipse() fails to detect obvious ellipse's correct dimensions

Tags: python, opencv, ellipse

So I know that fitEllipse has some mishaps (see  [this question for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17159964/opencvs-fitellipse-sometimes-returns-completely-wrong-ellipses)), but why does it here fail completely to find an obvious ellipse's dimensions ?
Am I missing something ?

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img=cv2.imread(my_input_image,0)

#this will be the result image where I'll draw the found ellipse in red
img_res=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)


nzs=cv2.findNonZero(img)

#calling fitEllipse on the non zeros
ellipse=cv2.fitEllipse(nzs)

#drawing the found ellipse
img_res=cv2.ellipse(img_res,ellipse,(0,0,255),thickness=3)
```

Input image (8bit binary image) : [image]

Output image (RBG) :
[image]

`FindNonZero()` and `ellipse()` seem to be working ok AFAICT.
The issue is in `fitEllipse()`, printing its result shows it is off
Ouput of print(ellipse) yields

> ((270.2370300292969, 174.11227416992188), (130.22764587402344, 216.85084533691406), 116.81776428222656)

where according to documentation (OK, documentation of OCV2.4 but I don't think this function's behavior has changed in 3.2), the 3rd and 4th numbers are the width and length of the rotated rectangle. But here, they are smaller than the ones actually needed.

I'm using Python 2.7 and OpenCV 3.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fitEllipse` functions works correctly, but you gave it the wrong input.

You should give as input the **contour** of the ellipse, not all the points inside the ellipse.

You can easily get the contour using an edge detection algorithm, e.g, `cv2.Canny`

Comment: Ahha, as usual, I feel dumb.. Although this could maybe be made clearer in the documentation ? Thanks anyhow

Comment: The nane is pretty clear by itself, actually :) You want to fit an ellipse to a set of points... the point thus should belong to the ellipse. Remember that only points on the boundary satisfy the ellipse equation (i.e.=0). Points inside are <0, outside >0

Comment: I see what you mean, I was so focused on my application that I considered this function as a "fitDisc()" in my mind !