# how to detect 2d gaussians in an image?

Tags: gaussian, mode, ellipse, data-fitting, astronomy

Suppose I have an image like this: [image]

I would like to fit a number of Gaussians to the image. Number of Gaussians is not known a priori.

This question is generally asked tool/software based (like how can i found by using ...)

So, my question is which way is a good solution to find peaks in an image like this and fit ellipses.

What is the name/solution of this problem in the literature?

bivariate Gaussian fitting/ellipse fitting/mode seeking (mean shift)/ multivariate kde/mixture of Gaussians ...?

My ultimate goal is to find point sources in astronomical images and i am aware of CLEAN algorithm and sextractor tool.

Note: Answers that describing algorithm in brief would be more helpful.

Comment: You may be interested in something like this: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_circle/hough_circle.html as explained also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860667/writing-robust-color-and-size-invariant-circle-detection-with-opencv-based-on

Comment: i think circle detection is a different problem. My shapes are ellipses.

Comment: So you may need this: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/bounding_rotated_ellipses/bounding_rotated_ellipses.html and consider this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13760110/using-opencv-fitellipse-for-circle-fitting/17820398#17820398

Comment: it uses a global threshold value to first convert image to binary and then find contours and fit ellipses this is not what i am talking about. i think you should review your links before posting them

Comment: Sorry, I thought that for "solution to find peaks in an image like this and fit ellipses" you could consider a library that is able to "find the different features of contours, like area, perimeter, centroid, bounding box etc" as explained here: http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contour_features/py_contour_features.html but you were surely asking for something else. In the wrong site, BTW.

Comment: i am asking for in the right place but i think you are working in opencv marketing unit. Because they are all unrelated to the topic.

Answer (score 1):

Sextractor is clearly the reference here. One alternative is photutils, an Astropy affiliated project:

- It provides [source detection](https://photutils.readthedocs.io/en/stable/detection.html) methods, which seems to work reasonably well. Also in the recent 0.2 version a deblending function was added.
- It also provides [aperture photometry](https://photutils.readthedocs.io/en/stable/aperture.html) and [PSF photometry](https://photutils.readthedocs.io/en/stable/psf.html).

It is a young package, so it should be used with some care, but it can do a good job (it depends also on your data).
There are also some software that use priors (position, shapes), for example TPHOT ([1505.02516](https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.02516)).

Comment: I fixed the source detection link but could not find an updated link for Gaussian PSF

Comment: great! I'm looking at images of spots on a phosphor screen from electron diffraction rather than stars, but photutils' source detection is very close to what I need and it's easy to find and modify.